# Accessing Office 365 or Exchange through Java Web Services

Tags: javascript, rest, exchange-server, office365

I need to get Mail and Calendar data from Office 365.

[Mail Calendar and Contact Rest APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection5) provides rest APIs to fetch data.

When I try to hit the URL provided by Rest API from the browser window, the site prompts for authentication and on providing credentials, the feed gets displayed.

But when I programmatically call the REST API through JavaScript, I get a 403 Error. It doesn't prompt for an authentication.

Is there a way to set authentication headers to these REST services?
I don't want to use Azure services to manage these services.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use OAUTH. 
Have your tried base64 encoded auth credentials using Authorization header as part of your Http request.

For example:

```
   var authz = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user + ":" + password));
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authz);
```